# Compare scanned image (label) with original

Tags: image-processing

There is an original high quality label. After it's been printed we scan a sample and want to compare it with original to find errors in printed text for example. Original and scanned images are almost of the same size (but a bit different).

ImageMagic can do it great but not with scanned image (I suppose it compares it bitwise but scanned image contains to much "noise").

Is there an utility that can so such a comparison? Or may be an algorithm (implemented or easy to implement) - like the one that uses Cauchy–Schwarz inequality in signal processing?

Adding sample pics.

**Original:-**

[image: Original]

**Scanned:-**

[image: Scanned]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Further Thoughts**

As I explained in the comments, I think the registration of the original and scanned images is going to be important as your scans are not exactly horizontal nor the same size. To do a crude registration, you could find some points of high-contrast that are hopefully unique in the original image. So, say I wanted one on the top-left (called `tl.jpg`), one in the top-right (`tr.jpg`), one in the bottom-left (`bl.jpg`) and one in the bottom-right (`br.jpg`). I might choose these:

[image][[image]]
[[image]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5erj.jpg)[image]

I can now find these in the original image and in the scanned image using a sub-image search, for example:

```
compare -metric RMSE -subimage-search original.jpg tl.jpg a.png b.png 
1148.27 (0.0175214) @ 168,103
```

[image][image]

That shows me where the sub-image has been found, and the second (greyish) image shows me a white peak where the image is actually located. It also tells me that the sub image is at coordinates [168,103] in the original image.

```
compare -metric RMSE -subimage-search scanned.jpg tl.jpg a.png b.png 
7343.29 (0.112051) @ 173,102
```

And now I know that same point is at coordinates [173,102] in the scanned image. So I need to transform [173,102] to [168,103].

I then need to do that for the other sub images:

```
compare -metric RMSE -subimage-search scanned.jpg br.jpg result.png 
8058.29 (0.122962) @ 577,592
```

[image][image]

Ok, so we can get 4 points, one near each corner in the original image, and their corresponding locations in the scanned image. Then we need to do an affine transformation - which I may, or may not do in the future. There are notes on how to do it [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/affine/).

**Original Answer**

It would help if you were able to supply some sample images to show what sort of problems you are expecting with the labels. However, let's assume you have these:

label.png

[image]

unhappy.png

[image]

unhappy2.png

[image]

I have only put a red border around them so you can see the edges on this white background.

If you use Fred Weinhaus's script `similar` from his superb [website](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/similar/index.php), you can now compute a normalised cross correlation between the original image and the unhappy ones. So, taking the original label and the one with one track of white across it, they come out pretty similar (96%)

```
./similar label.png unhappy.png
Similarity Metric: 0.960718
```

If we now try the more unhappy one with two tracks across it, they are less similar (92%):

```
./similar label.png unhappy2.png
Similarity Metric: 0.921804
```

Ok, that seems to work. We now need to deal with the shifted and differently sized scan, so I will attempt to trim them to only get the important stuff and blur them to lose any noise and resize to a standardised size for comparison using a little script.

```
#!/bin/bash
image1=$1
image2=$2
fuzz="10%"
filtration="-median 5x5"
resize="-resize 500x300"
echo DEBUG: Preparing $image1 and $image2...

# Get cropbox from blurred image
cropbox=$(convert "$image1" -fuzz $fuzz $filtration -format %@ info:)
# Now crop original unblurred image and resize to standard size
convert "$image1" -crop "$cropbox" $resize +repage im1.png

# Get cropbox from blurred image
cropbox=$(convert "$image2" -fuzz $fuzz $filtration -format %@ info:)
# Now crop original unblurred image and resize to standard size
convert "$image2" -crop "$cropbox" $resize +repage im2.png

# Now compare using Fred's script
./similar im1.png im2.png
```

We can now compare the original label with a new image called `unhappy-shifted.png`

[image]

```
./prepare label.png unhappy-shifted.png
DEBUG: Preparing label.png and unhappy-shifted.png...
Similarity Metric: 1
```

And we can see they compare the same despite being shifted. Obviously I cannot see your images, how noisy they are, what sort of background you have, how big they are, what colour they are and so on - so you may need to adjust the preparation where I have just done a median filter. Maybe you need a blur and/or a threshold. Maybe you need to go to greyscale.

Comment: Thank you, Mark! I added example pics (just made them 30% of original size) - they are a bit more complex. Can you please tell me if you think this method will work for them too?

Comment: Mmmm... it is more difficult with your images because they are rotated relative to each other and so registration/alignment errors are going to dominate or skew the results. I think you would need to find control points near each corner of the image and do an affine transformation to align the scan to the original then proceed with the method above. It's not something I am likely to have time to do soon. I would probably identify a smallish square where the entropy/contrast is high near each corner and do a sub-image search for that in the scanned image to identify control points.

Comment: Thank you a lot, Mark!! Even if you find time not very soon it'll be great if you post your ideas. Btw it also required to show the place where the pics are different. So I think I'll pause with this task for now to find out more about the subject.

Comment: One question - is it always the same original label? Or do you have lots of different ones?

Comment: The idea is to use for different ones, not the one I showed here - it's just an example. But I think we can compare original with several scans of the same label.